# How to Display more than 1000 records in a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I am new to SalesForce, I have tried using  its giving me an error as limit 1000.

Suggest me some solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use readonly attribute to display more than 1000 records.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I have implemented readonly attribute in my page, iam getting error as "730 kb
exceeded view state size".

Answer (score 2):

Repeater control has limit of showing only 1000 records.

You can use REST API to fetch record and JQUery to render it. [This is good article to give you base that how to use REST API in VF.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-visualforce-pages-revisited.html)

Comment: I don't have any web services i am getting my data from controller.

Comment: @VivekP You don't need a web service call. You can construct the data payload in a method, and expose it by a RemoteAction function or as a plain JSON object directly in the page, where it can be processed by code you write. You don't need any jQuery experience, either, just plain [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) should suffice, unless you want to load additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Jitendra Zaa has a good solution above, but I would also suggest that displaying more than 1,000 rows in a visualforce page can cause other problems. Depending on how the VF page is set up, for example, you can run into view state errors, or just general slowness. Users may also find it difficult to parse through this many records.

I would consider implementing pagination and/or some kind of search functionality with various filters, so that users can view a smaller subset of records (if, of course, this works for your needs).

Comment: How many records we can in pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RemoteActions. This is a starting point http://blog.enree.co/2013/01/apex-javascript-what-is-remoteaction.html